# Hibernate MappingException Unknown entity

Tags: java, hibernate, maven

I am getting a mapping exception trying to use Hibernate - in a stand alone java application (using netbeans 8). I have configured my hibernate.cfg.xml and setup my hbm.xml file and mapped it, See below on how my app is configured. This is my first time using hibernate.

```
Dec 04, 2015 9:23:26 AM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment buildBytecodeProvider
INFO: HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
Dec 04, 2015 9:23:26 AM org.hibernate.boot.jaxb.internal.stax.LocalXmlResourceResolver resolveEntity
WARN: HHH90000012: Recognized obsolete hibernate namespace http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration. Use namespace http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration instead.  Support for obsolete DTD/XSD namespaces may be removed at any time.
Dec 04, 2015 9:23:27 AM org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.java.JavaReflectionManager <clinit>
INFO: HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.0.0.Final}
Dec 04, 2015 9:23:27 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl configure
WARN: HHH10001002: Using Hibernate built-in connection pool (not for production use!)
Dec 04, 2015 9:23:27 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH10001005: using driver [com.mysql.jdbc.Driver] at URL [jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/shlama_dry_clean?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull]
Dec 04, 2015 9:23:27 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH10001001: Connection properties: {user=root, password=****}
Dec 04, 2015 9:23:27 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH10001003: Autocommit mode: false
Dec 04, 2015 9:23:27 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.PooledConnections <init>
INFO: HHH000115: Hibernate connection pool size: 20 (min=1)
Dec 04, 2015 9:23:27 AM org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect <init>
INFO: HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.MappingException: Unknown entity: com.beraben.drycleanpos3.entities.GarmentType
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.getEntityPersister(SessionFactoryImpl.java:776)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.getEntityPersister(SessionImpl.java:1462)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:100)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:192)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:38)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:177)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveEventListener.performSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:32)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.onSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:73)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireSave(SessionImpl.java:678)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:670)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:665)
    at com.beraben.drycleanpos3.app.mainTest.main(mainTest.java:36)
```

My hibernate.cfg.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN" "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
  <session-factory>
    <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/shlama_dry_clean?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.password">root</property>
    <mapping class="" file="" jar="" package="" resource="garmenttypes.hbm.xml"/>
  </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

my garmenttype mapping file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN" "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="com.beraben.drycleanpos3.entities.GarmentType" table="garment_types">
        <id name="id" column="id">
            <generator class="increment"/>
        </id>
        <property name="name" column="name"/>
        <property name="description" column="description"/>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

my GarmentType entity class

```
package com.beraben.drycleanpos3.entities;

/**
 *
 * @author Evan
 */
public class GarmentType {
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private String description;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

}
```

My main run class

```
import com.beraben.drycleanpos3.entities.GarmentType;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistryBuilder;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;

/**
 *
 * @author Evan
 */
public class mainTest {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Configuration configuration = new Configuration().configure();
        StandardServiceRegistryBuilder builder = 
                new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(configuration.getProperties());

        SessionFactory factory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(builder.build());
        Session session = factory.openSession();

        GarmentType garmentType = new GarmentType();
        garmentType.setName("Pants");
        garmentType.setDescription("Pants");

        session.beginTransaction();
        session.save(garmentType);
        session.getTransaction().commit();

    }

}
```

My pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.beraben</groupId>
    <artifactId>DryCleanPOS3</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>unknown-jars-temp-repo</id>
            <name>A temporary repository created by NetBeans for libraries and jars it could not identify. Please replace the dependencies in this repository with correct ones and delete this repository.</name>
            <url>file:${project.basedir}/lib</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.4.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.37</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>unknown.binary</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java-5.1.23-bin</artifactId>
            <version>SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>3.5.6-Final</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
</project>
```

Comment: In my case problem was in incorrect package name:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36524202/hibernate-maven-mappingexception-unknown-entity/62213401#62213401

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please double check the name `garmenttypes.hbm.xml` correct.

May be hibernate cannot find the `garmenttypes.hbm.xml`

Try with the following.

```
Configuration configuration = new Configuration().configure("hibernate.cfg.xml");
configuration.addResource("garmenttypes.hbm.xml");
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: What was the exact issue?

Answer (score 0):

Try to put @Entity annotation above GarmentType class.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using hbm files. Try to downgrade the Hibernate-core version.
I used hibernate-core:4.3.5-Final
And it worked for me.