# Hibernate Maven MappingException Unknown entity

Tags: java, hibernate, maven

I got an exception when I use hibernate in Maven. The hibernate version is 5.1.0.Final. 
The exception is: 
[image]
Here is my project structure:
[image]

Here is my Entity class ABC:

```
package com;
import javax.persistence.*;
@Entity

@Table(name = "abc_inf")

public class ABC {

    @Id@GeneratedValue
    private Integer id;

    private String name;

    public ABC() {
    }

    setters and getters omitted 

}
```

Here is my main class:

```
package com;

import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistryBuilder;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;
import org.hibernate.service.ServiceRegistry;
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Configuration conf = new Configuration().configure();
        ServiceRegistry sr = new             StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(conf.getProperties()).build();
        SessionFactory sf = conf.buildSessionFactory(sr);
        Session session = sf.openSession();

        ABC abc = new ABC();
        abc.setName("abc");

        session.save(abc);
        session.flush();
        session.close();
        sf.close();
    }
}
```

Here is my hibernate.cfg.xml:

```
<hibernate-configuration>
  <session-factory>
    mysql connection and properties settings omitted
    <mapping class="com.ABC"/>
  </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Comment: Can you please  confirm you are calling the hibernate.cfg.xml to configure your entity before you run your main program

Comment: it uses the hibernate.cfg.xml, otherwise it would throw some connection exception as it could not connect to the database in the first place. I also printed the properties from Configuration, it is identical to the ones defined in hibernate.cfg.xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a Hibernate 5 configuration problem. You can't use this code to build a session factory

```
Configuration conf = new Configuration().configure();
ServiceRegistry sr = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(conf.getProperties()).build();
SessionFactory sf = conf.buildSessionFactory(sr);
```

Use this instead

```
SessionFactory sf = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
```

Refer for additional notes

[Hibernate 5 :- org.hibernate.MappingException: Unknown entity](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32711654/3405171)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is solved if it uses Hibernate version 4

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the annotated classes to the hibernate config. Use the following code

```
AnnotationConfiguration conf = new AnnotationConfiguration();
conf.addAnnotatedClass(ABC.class);
SessionFactry sf = conf.configure(hbmFile).buildSessionFactory();
```

Comment: Using `AnnotationConfiguration` is valid only for Hibernate 3. This code will work with `Configuration`, but it is need to add every persistent class.

Answer (score 0):

As for my case i'm use `LocalSessionFactoryBean` and `setPackagesToScan`, and services, writed for audit entities work fine.

But!!!

In our project we have table `EntityInfo` with column `entityname`, for example,

`entytyname = bel.rdigital.cashbox.models.cbmain.merchantcore.versions.CBVersions`

and this persist in db. Then I refactored entity `CBVersions` and transfer it to package

`bel.rdigital.cashbox.models.cbmain.versions.cashbox.CBVersions`,

but in db stayed old package, and than, when I using method `CrossTypeRevisionChangesReader.findEntitiesGroupByRevisionType(revision)`,

I get exception `Unknown entity: bel.rdigital.cashbox.models.cbmain.merchantcore.versions.CBVersions`

So, this exaption means, that hiberante not find entity... Problem may be in package scanning or in location entity...

Comment: You shouldn't use questions as the answers.

Comment: where is question in my answer??? I simply explain our situation, and how i solve this problem!!!

Comment: Okay, let it be an answer. There is not anything related to Spring in the original question by the way.